# tinymce removing my markup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using tinymce as my editor when I go in to HTML view and add in my own custom code it won't let me it strips out the markup, how can I disable this feature? For example I added a link tag  but did not add text between the tags and it removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the settins in your valid_elements and valid_children parameter.
If needed you have to add elements to it in order to not have them stripped out.

Comment: Here is what I currently got:                                   valid_elements : '*[*]',
valid_children : "+body[style],-body[div],p[strong|a|#text]"         it is still stripping out the the content